# ThreadLocalRandom() alternative for Android API level 19 and below?

Tags: java, android

In my application I'm using `ThreadLocalRandom()` to generate seed, but It works only in **API level 21 +**, can I use `Random` and get the same result?

here is the code:

```
public String generateSeed(int length, boolean isNumeric) {
        String key = "";
        if (isNumeric) {
            while (key.length() < length) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    key = key + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 9);
                } else {
                    //TODO: ThreadLocalRandom alternative
                }

            }
        } else {
            while (key.length() < length) {
                key = key + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
            }
        }
        key = key.substring(0, length);
        return key;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Random`. It does the same. You may want to consider using the currentTimeMillis as the seed though, but you don't have to supply any arguments to create it if you don't want a custom seed

Comment: So `key = key + new Random().nextInt(9);` should do the job right?

Comment: You may want to store the instance to avoid multiple recreations (memory concern) but yes, that should do it. If you want to generate a random number including 9, use 10 as the limit instead. If you want 1-9 inclusive, add one to the random result